# Unable to launch JSON doc from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to connect ElasticSearch with Kibana.Both are installed on the same machine.Modified the Kibana(config.js) which is pointing to ElasticSearch Server.

config.js settings

```
define(['settings'],
function (Settings) {


  return new Settings({

    elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200",

    kibana_index: "kibana-int",

    panel_names: [
      'histogram',
      'map',
      'pie',
      'table',
      'filtering',
      'timepicker',
      'text',
      'fields',
      'hits',
      'dashcontrol',
      'column',
      'derivequeries',
      'trends',
      'bettermap',
      'query',
      'terms'
    ]
  });
});
```

I have created the index "twitter" for this JSON doc

```
curl -XPUT ['http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1]' -d '{
    "user" : "test",
    "post_date" : "2011-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}'
```

I did check the indices folder in ElasticSearch where 'twitter' index is present. But when I try to hit this url

[http://localhost/kibana/index.html#/dashboard/file/twitter.json]

I get this error :

> Error No index found at 
>   [http://localhost:9200/INDEX_MISSING/_mapping]. Please create at least
>   one index.If you're using a proxy ensure it is configured correctly.

I did clear the browser cache and retest,but still occurring.
Webserver - Apache HTTP

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding config.js contents to your question might help to get a better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pointing to 'twitter' index in json file did solve the problem.

"index": {
    "interval": "none",
    "pattern": "[logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD",
    "default": "twitter"
  }